# Area 51 voting problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting, area-51

There is a problem with the front-end voting system on Area 51. When you first click on the score of an example question to view the up- and downvote count (only available for 1K+ users), and then try to vote, the votecount is incorrect.

How to reproduce:

- Go to a random [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) proposal in the definition phase
- Choose a random example question and click on the score to view the individual up- and downvote counts

[image]

- Vote up or down
- The votecount is now incorrect

[image]

If you retract the vote right away, the wrong count is updated correctly:

[image]

Refreshing the page does show the right value (15 after the upvote in this example).

Comment: Oh wow, "incorrect" doesn't quite cover it. :)

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks for the screenshots!

Comment: They just forgot to cast to integer, so "14" + "1" is indeed "141". :)

Comment: I always thought it was funny how this bug only occurred on Area 51 and no other SE site. I'm glad you reported it. I've seen that bug for a long time but just never got around to reporting it myself. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Heh, good catch. This is fixed now.