# Area 51 voting problem - part 2

Tags: bug, voting, area-51

Yesterday, a front-end [problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184462/205264) was fixed. However, there's something else: in some cases, it isn't possible anymore to view the individual up and downvote numbers on an example question. Again: only front-end stuff, a refresh solves it. Also this question is related to the 1K privilege of viewing the separated votecounts.

I found two cases of this behaviour:

1. View individual counts first, then vote, then try to view the individual counts again. This isn't possible anymore!
2. Vote first, then view individual counts, then unvote, then try to view the individual counts again. This isn't possible anymore!

In both cases, this is possible on other sites, so I think this should be considered a bug(?).